# Unable to change image in jScrollPane upon clicking next

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a jframe where i'm adding an image that will change as i click next.I have written a code but it doesn't work.Here is the code:

```
    i++;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(mean.get(0));
    Image image = icon.getImage(); // transform it
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(180, 140,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way
    icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
    jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane( label );
```

Please help

Comment: Don't you have to tell Java to `repaint`?

Comment: Tried it.Did not work

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which initializes `jScrollPane1`, and also the code that adds it to your JFrame.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Base your MSCVE / SSCCE on this [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556).

Comment: @camickr...That question has the answer on how to add an image...Here i want to change the existing image

Comment: ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(myPicture);
        Image image = icon.getImage();
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(180, 140,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
        icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        jLabel4 = new JLabel( icon );
        jLabel4.repaint();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jLabel4); //This solved my problem @camickr.Here my question was different

Comment: @ani `That question has the answer on how to add an image...Here i want to change the existing image` - read the answer and comments. Also learn to read the API. There is no need to ask a question in the forum every time you have a little problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with:

```
jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane( label );
```

The field `jScrollPane` whose object was placed in the JFrame is set to another JScrollPane, whose object is not added in the GUI.

Store the original label in a field, say `jLabel1` and set that label.

A `repaint` might be needed.

Comment: I tried it.But its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

- revalidate()
- repaint()

See an explanation of why here [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Comment: I tried it.But its not working

Answer (score 0):

Add this to end of your code `jScrollPane1`. If haven't `JFrame` created already create one like below then add that `jScrollPane1` to `JFrame`.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

There is also set the layout as `BorderLayout` but you can try other layouts or without adding layout also.

Comment: I have already created a jframe

Comment: so you dont have to create a `JFrame` just put your `JFrame` name instead of `frame`

Comment: @ani change `frame` to your `JFrame` variable name.

Comment: Then other components will be reloaded..I don't want that..I simply want to change that particular image.

Comment: @ani use `removeAll()` to remove the others.